# how does links__system_main_menu() work?

Tags: theming

How does the below code work at a high level?

```
print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
  'links' => $main_menu,
  'attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'main-menu-links',
    'class' => array('links', 'clearfix'),
  ),
  'heading' => array(
    'text' => t('Main menu'),
    'level' => 'h2',
    'class' => array('element-invisible'),
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal renders the array argument you passed by looking up a suitable theme hook for `links__system_main_menu`.

The meaning of the argument should be documented in the module that provides the theme hook.